# Java SSO against a linux tomcat (mod_jk)

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, single-sign-on, mod-jk

We are using mod_jk as load balancer between the java client apps and the tomcat server. Any service request can reach another tomcat. That makes the handshake more difficult.
The Server is Linux based what means for us we **can't use waffle** (it's for windows only).

NTLM is also not a option for our company because of the security (deprecation).

Using Spengo for HTTP request authentification is not possible. We have some requests that have to be accepted without any login/permission (public permission).

Are there any other alternatives or working examples with Spengo to realize a SSO for the windows clients?